# How to append list and reload tableView in viewcontroller2 from viewcontroller1 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

//1st VC:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bookmark = BookmarkVC()
    var bookmarkAppend = [" "]

    @IBAction func addToBookmarks(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if cityLabel.text != "city" && cityLabel.text != "" && !bookmark.bookmarkList.contains(cityLabel.text!){
            bookmark.bookmarkList.append(cityLabel.text!)
            //bookmarkAppend.append(cityLabel.text!)
            //bookmark.tableView.reloadData()
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookmarkSegue", sender: nil)
            //bookmark.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            return
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "bookmarkSegue" {
            if let bookmarkVC = segue.destination as? BookmarkVC {
                //detailVC.textToDisplay = bookmarkList[ip.row]
                for i in bookmarkAppend {
                    bookmarkVC.bookmarkList.append(i)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

//2nd VC:

```
class BookmarkVC: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue2" {
            if let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailVC, let ip = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                detailVC.textToDisplay = bookmarkList[ip.row]
            }
        }
    }

    var bookmarkList = ["London", "Paris", "Moskow", "Budapest", "Barcelona", "Milano", "Roma", "Ottawa", "Berlin", "New York"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

The rest of the code works fine.My problem is that if I append the temporary list in VC1 and use it with segue, somehow I can't limit the number of the same cities in the list. But if I append the VC2 list, it won't appear on the tableview. I guess there is a problem with reloading the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot work, because `BookmarkVC()` is not the instance you expect.

My suggestion is to pass the new bookmark in the `sender` parameter of `performSegue`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func addToBookmarks(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let city = cityLabel.text!
        if !city.isEmpty && city != "city" {

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookmarkSegue", sender: city)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "bookmarkSegue" {
           let city = sender as! String
           let bookmarkVC = segue.destination as! BookmarkVC 
           if !bookmarkVC.bookmarkList.contains(city) {
               bookmarkVC.bookmarkList.append(city)
           }
       }
    }
```

In `BookmarkVC` you have to reload the table view in `viewDidLoad` because this is the first place where it's guaranteed that the outlets are connected

```
class BookmarkVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var bookmarkList = ["London", "Paris", "Moskow", "Budapest", "Barcelona", "Milano", "Roma", "Ottawa", "Berlin", "New York"]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

---

---

If the segue must **not** be performed if the bookmark already exists you have to keep the bookmarks in `ViewController` and pass the entire array to `BookmarkVC` (which I'd prefer anyway)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var bookmarkList = ["London", "Paris", "Moskow", "Budapest", "Barcelona", "Milano", "Roma", "Ottawa", "Berlin", "New York"]

    @IBAction func addToBookmarks(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let city = cityLabel.text!
        if !city.isEmpty && city != "city" && !bookmarkList.contains(city) {
            bookmarkList.append(city)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookmarkSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "bookmarkSegue" {
           let bookmarkVC = segue.destination as! BookmarkVC 
           bookmarkVC.bookmarkList = self.bookmarkList
        }
    }
```

...

```
class BookmarkVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var bookmarkList = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```